# Google maps api directions JSON output get parameter of compass?

Tags: ios, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm working on an new app in ios dev where I need also using Google maps api.
I read about google maps api web services,json and there outputs parameters:"route","legs","step",etc. In my app I have one leg (no waypoints) and x steps & for each step I calculate the compass angle - not in true time (getheading() or something).
That is to say, getting the angle (clockwise north) in the point of view of the specific step and use it later is my goal.

So how do I get this compass parameter in the json output? 
worng exp:

```
   {
   "staus":"ok",
   "routes": [{ .... 
      "legs":[{ 
         "steps":[{...
            "start_location":
            "end_location":

            /*------------------------*\
            ??? "compass_angle": ???  
            /*------------------------*\

           ]}
       ]}      
    ]}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the formula here to calculate the initial bearing between two coordinates:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html